# Adding calculated fields with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, vector-layer, qgsexpression

In the Memory provider described in [PyQGIS Cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html#memory-provider) and in the question [Creating new empty vector layer with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30261/how-to-create-a-new-empty-vector-layer-programmatically) I can see how to create a Vector Layer programmatically using standard fields (`String`, `Int`, `Double`).

With PyQGIS/QGIS 1.8.0, is it possible to programmatically add calculated fields like the ones defined using the Field Calculator?

After reading about [`QgsExpression`](https://qgis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/08_expressions.html) I'm thinking in something like this:

```py
exp = QgsExpression('Column * 3')
pr.addAttributes( [ QgsField( "fieldName", QVariant.Expression, exp ) ] )
```

Comment: Is you question about adding the attribute, modifying the value of an attribute or about the expression syntax/parser present in the field calculator? Could you outline a short example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Is about adding a new attribute defined with the parser present in the field calculator. I've edited the question to add an example that tries to clarify what I want to achieve.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To accomplish this, you have to take a two-step approach. The first step is to create the field, the second one is to loop over all your features, evaluate the expression and update the attribute for each feature.

`vl` is your `QgsVectorLayer`

### QGIS 2.0

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QgsField, QgsExpression, QgsFeature

vl.startEditing()

#step 1
myField = QgsField( 'myattr', QVariant.Int )
vl.addAttribute( myField )
idx = vl.fieldNameIndex( 'myattr' )

#step 2
e = QgsExpression( 'Column * 3' )
e.prepare( vl.pendingFields() )

for f in vl.getFeatures():
    f[idx] = e.evaluate( f )
    vl.updateFeature( f )

vl.commitChanges()
```

### QGIS 1.8

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QgsField, QgsExpression, QgsFeature

vl.startEditing()

#step 1
myField = QgsField( 'myattr', QVariant.Int )
vl.addAttribute( myField )
idx = vl.fieldNameIndex( 'myattr' )

#step 2
e = QgsExpression( 'Column * 3' )
e.prepare( vl.pendingFields() )

f = QgsFeature()
vl.select( vl.pendingAllAttributesList() )
while vl.nextFeature( f ):
    vl.changeAttributeValue( f.id(), idx, e.evaluate( f ) )

vl.commitChanges()
```