# What are QGIS equivalent functions for ArcPy's Update/Delete Row/Field?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to reprogram some scripts from ArcPy to QGIS (1.8 or 2.0) and there are some simple functions that I want to be able to redo but unfortunately documentation in QGIS is lacking in certain areas.

Namely the three most important for me are:

[Add Field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000047000000) - Add field

```
arcpy.AddField_management(Feature, "ID", "SHORT")
```

[Calculate Field Management](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004m000000) - Update that field

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Feature,"ID","!FID!")
```

[Update/Delete Rows](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001q000000) - Update/Delete rows based on condition (without copying the shapefile)

```
keep = ["Bob","Janet","John","Mike"]
Counter = 0
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(Feature)

for row in rows:
    if row.Name in keep:
        row.ID = Counter
        rows.updateRow(row)
    else:
        rows.deleteRow(row)
    Counter += 1
```

Now I can iterate through each feature in QGIS using SEXTANTE and obtain its geometry which I should be able to rewrite into a new shapefile and thereby update/delete a row or field. Starting with something along the lines of...

```
layer = st.getobject(Polygon)
features = st.getfeatures(layer)
for f in features:
    f.geometry().asPolygon()
```

but I can't find a simple solution for those functions mentioned above?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what the aim of the last part of your question is. Why do you mention SEXTANTE? You ask for a method to rewrite into a new shapefile, but your code excerpt does nothing such afaics.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following examples are based on the (soon-to-be-released) QGIS 2.0 API. This has changed since 1.8, so the syntax for this version will differ in some places.

The best resource for 1.8 compliant solutions and in-depth explanation for background of parameters (also apply for 2.0) are the [PyQGIS Cookbook](http://qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html)

We'll assume you already have a reference to a vector layer called `vl` obtained by e.g.

```
vl = iface.activeLayer()
```

### Transactions

The following examples are working in a transaction (locally cached in QGIS). Before starting the edit session you have to call

```
vl.startEditing()
```

and end it with

```
vl.commitChanges()
```

to write your changes to the data source. or

```
vl.rollBack()
```

to dismiss the changes

You could also work directly on `vl.dataProvider()` and forget about the transaction control statements. (Resulting in autocommit-like behaviour)

### Adding a field

[QgsVectorLayer.addAttribute( QgsField )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a2524a71bea9e35600788f525b49109ae)

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
vl.addAttribute( QgsField( 'fieldname', QVariant.String ) )
```

This only works, if the dataprovider implements the AddAttributes capability. You can check this with:

```
if vl.dataProvider().capabilities() & QgsVectorDataProvider.ChangeAttributeValues
```

### Calculate fields

See this answer:

[Is it possible to programmatically add calculated fields?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34974/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-add-calculated-fields)

It's still aimed at 1.8, so instead of `vl.select()` you have to call the 2.0 equivalent `vl.getFeatures()` ( see [QGIS API changes](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Python_plugin_API_changes_from_18_to_20#Vector-layer-API-changes) )

### Update rows

[QgsVectorLayer.updateField( featureId, fieldIndex, value )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#adc159d56ea0e1be1bef381b56ba0ce31)

```
vl.updateField( 1000, 5, 'hello' )
```

Preqrequisites check (optional):

```
if vl.dataProvider().capabilities() & QgsVectorDataProvider.ChangeAttributeValues
```

To know the fieldIndex, you can use [`QgsVectorLayer.pendingFields()`](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ad64023f87dd3812c413e6081dade2189)

Edit:
See also the comment by NathanW which mentions the well readable [`QgsVectorLayer.updateFeature( feature )`](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a125a2f00703d7e3c07b2c26801799ee1) method.

### Delete rows

[QgsVectorLayer.deleteFeature( featureId )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a02acd03beff88e089c83b4dbf6f30ba7)

```
vl.deleteFeature( 1000 )
```

Optional prerequisites check:

```
if vl.dataProvider().capabilities() & QgsVectorDataProvider.DeleteFeatures
```

Comment: Using `feature[5] = 'hello'` and `layer.updateFeature(feature)` is better then using vl.updateField IMO

Answer (score 6):

This is how you would do your code in PyQGIS:

```
keep = ["Bob","Janet","John","Mike"]

for counter, feature in enumerate(layer.getFeatures()):
    if feature['Name'] in keep:
        feature['ID'] = counter
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
    else:
        layer.deleteFeature(feature.id())
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [PyQGIS cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/) and [vector layer modification section](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html#modifying-vector-layers) in particular.