# Applying Field Calculator with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, qgsexpression

I would like to use Field Calculator in PyQGIS to update the existing column based on certain conditions.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think this [answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/59724/9022) might help.

Comment: I agreed, you don't need the Field Calculator with PyQGIS, everything can be done in Python (look at [Using Vector Layers](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no prebuilt class to do the magic the Field Calculator does (I am planning on adding it at some stage) however it's quite simple:

```py
expression = QgsExpression("1 + 1")
# This allows field lookup
index = layer.fieldNameIndex("UpdateField")
expression.prepare(layer.pendingFields())
layer.startEditing()

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    value = expression.evaluate(feature)
    layer.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), index, value)

layer.commitChanges()
```

A couple of notes: We are using `changeAttributeValue` because it's faster but does require use to use the feature id and field index, another way which might be as fast but is clearer to read is:

```py
expression = QgsExpression("1 + 1")
# This allows field lookup
expression.prepare(layer.pendingFields())

layer.startEditing()

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    value = expression.evaluate(feature)
    feature["UpdateField"] = value
    layer.updateFeature(feature)

layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: I am testing this code, but I get an error on the expression.prepareFields(layer.pendingFields()) line? QgsExpression' object has no attribute 'prepareFields'

Comment: please use 'prepare' instead of 'prepareFields'