# Copying values from virtual field to non-virtual field using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

Using the python console, I am trying to copy values from a virtual field into another non-virtual field. Both fields are *integer* types but I get `NULL` in the non-virtual field. I followed the answer in this post: [Is it possible to programmatically add calculated fields?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34974/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-add-calculated-fields)

The following code works if both fields are non-virtual but doesn't work if copying from a virtual field. Here is the code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QgsField, QgsExpression, QgsFeature

vl = QgsVectorLayer("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Test\\Layer.shp", "Layer", "ogr")
vl.startEditing()

idx = vl.fieldNameIndex( 'Field_1' )             # Field_1 is the non-virtual field

e = QgsExpression( ' "Field_2" ' )               # Field_2 is the virtual field
e.prepare( vl.pendingFields() )

for f in vl.getFeatures():
    f[idx] = e.evaluate( f )
    vl.updateFeature( f )

vl.commitChanges()
```

This works manually through the **Field Calculator**.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/395  ?

Comment: @SIslam - Thanks for the link buddy! I'll see if I can do this by accessing the field calculator tool from pyqgis :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtual Fields are saved in the project, not in the layer itself. Shapefiles do not know the concept of virtual layers, only QGIS (projects) do.

If you dynamically load a layer like in the sample code you pasted, there is no project involved and hence no virtual field specification loaded.

You can check with the following code that there is no Field_2:

```
fields = vl.pendingFields()
for i in range(fields.count()):
    fields[i].name()
```

You can either

- load a project with a layer that has virtual field definitions attached and work with the layer loaded this way.

or

- you can [add a virtual field](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a041b1d9f334eb3c31c893f5d130f7f0d) with the help of python code to a dynamically loaded layer.

So the answer is: the code in the sample does not fail to work because of problems with the virtual field - it does not work because there is no virtual field at all.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, that makes a lot of sense. I was hoping to include the code in a project macro but I'll play around and see if adding a new virtual field, instead of copying values from one, suits my work =)

Comment: If you deliver it with a project macro you could define the virtual fields on a layer in that project and then make your python script use the project layer instead of a dynamically loaded one?

Comment: Huh good shout! I will see if I can achieve that as it sounds like it should do exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks again!