# Adding field in PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I am trying to add and calculate a field for earthquakes selected within blast zones using the guidelines in this answer [Is it possible to programmatically add calculated fields?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34974/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-add-calculated-fields/59724#59724). Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
import processing

processing.runalg("qgis:selectbylocation", 
"/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/moment_all.shp", 
"/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/all_buffers.shp", ['within'], 0,0)

from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QgsField, QgsExpression, QgsFeature

moment_all = iface.activeLayer()

moment_all.startEditing()

blast = QgsField(‘myattr’, QVariant.Int )
moment_all.addAttribute(blast)
idx = moment_all.fieldNameIndex(‘myattr')
moment_all.commitChanges()

processing.runalg(“qgis:fieldcalculator”, 
“/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/moment_all.shp”, “blast”, 0, 10, 3, 
False, ““blast” = ‘b’”, None)
```

I used

```
execfile(r'/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/blast.py')
```

and my output error was:

```
    Python Console 
Use iface to access QGIS API interface or Type help(iface) for more info
execfile(r'/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/blast.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/blast.py", line 19            
blast = QgsField( âmyattrâ, QVariant.Int )
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: There is a typo/misuse of quotation marks `‘` in `blast = QgsField(‘myattr’, QVariant.Int )` and `idx = moment_all.fieldNameIndex(‘myattr')`. Use `'myattr'` or `"myattr"` and not `‘myattr‘`

Comment: that seems to have fixed the first section, though the last line is now saying "invalid character in Identifier". Any idea which character this would be? 


processing.runalg(“qgis:fieldcalculator”, 
“/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/moment_all.shp”, “blast”, 0, 10, 3, 
False, ““blast” = ‘b’”, None)

Comment: File "/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/blast.py", line 24
    processing.runalg(âqgis:fieldcalculatorâ, â/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/moment_all.shpâ, âblastâ, 0, 10, 3, False, ââblastâ = âbââ, None)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: try `'"blast"='b''` instead `""blast"='b'"`, if this help you I'll add this as an answer

Comment: hmm still invalid syntax with this change. I'll update if anything changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62419/discussion-between-oto-kalab-and-jrowley).

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo/misuse of quotation marks `‘` and `“` for strings in (notice the syntax highlighting):

```
blast = QgsField(‘myattr’, QVariant.Int ) 

#and 

idx = moment_all.fieldNameIndex(‘myattr')
```

Use `'myattr'` or `"myattr"` and not `‘myattr‘` (actually this gives you `âmyattrâ` in error)

Also, in the last line Use `"` and not `“`, and change the `processing.runalg` expression argument. You have to use tripple quotes, because of nested quotes (notice the syntax highlighting):

```
processing.runalg(“qgis:fieldcalculator”, “/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/moment_all.shp”, “blast”, 0, 10, 3, False, ““blast” = ‘b’”, None)
```

Expression argument:

```
#wrong:
""blast"='b'"   
#wrong:
'"blast"='b''
#correct:
'''"blast"='b\''''
```

You can check this with printing in prompt:

```
>>> print(""blast"='b'")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(""blast"='b'")
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print('"blast"='b'')
"blast"=
>>> print('''"blast"='b\'''')
"blast"='b'
```

The last one is the correct string expression you want. The code than should look like this:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", "/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/moment_all.shp", "blast", 0, 10, 3, False, '''"blast" = 'b\'''', None)
```

Comment: This resolved the first issue, however I am still having issues with the second. The syntax should be correct with the third option noted but I'm still receiving the following: 

    processing.runalg(“qgis:fieldcalculator”, “/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/moment_all.shp”, “blast”, 0, 10, 3, False, '''"blast"='b\'''', None)
  File "<input>", line 1
    processing.runalg(âqgis:fieldcalculatorâ, â/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/moment_all.shpâ, âblastâ, 0, 10, 3, False, '''"blast"='b\'''', None)
                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax