# PyQGIS 3: Create a layer with a primary key

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have  written a plugin for QGIS that is importing some data. In this plugin, I can create a memory layer for the data like I have described here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/349354/10123.

How can I create a primary key / feature id column on this table? In the QgsVectorDataProvider, I see I can use `pkAttributeIndexes` to list the fields making up the primary key, but how can I set it?